# Usando $Ajax para salvar nome de arquivos em um scaffold

Tags: javascript, ajax, scaffold

Eu venho trabalhando nisso mas n consigo resolver o meu problema. Eu possuo um código em JS que através de um input eu posso acessar um arquivo txt e obter seu nome. Também criei um scaffold Histórico para eu poder armazenar esse nome.

```
if (passAll === true) {
   var fullPath = document.getElementById('file').value;
     if (fullPath) {
       var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
       var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
         if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
            filename = filename.substring(1);
         }
     alert(filename);
     }
}
```

Eu recebi uma ideia de usar Ajax para, usando o método POST, enviar esse filename diretamente para o URL de criação do meu scaffold assim eu não precisaria digitar o filename, o que seria a forma normal, e salvar automaticamente (de alguma forma, agradeço se puder me explicar como eu poderia fazer isso).

Meu grande problema é em como usar o Ajax e onde usá-lo, no meu JS? Como?

Não sei mais o que adicionar aqui, acredito que todo scaffold criado seja o mesmo, então n colocarei o meu scaffold.

Comment: Eu n entendo o voto negativo, acreditei que minha pergunta estava clara, vc pode pensar que essa pergunta não é útil para vc mas eu possuo um problema e necessito ajuda

Comment: Como usar Ajax: [vanilla](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) e [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Salvar automaticamente vc faz na página requisitada.

Comment: Isso é exatamente o que eu não estou conseguindo entender, poderia me mostrar usando o meu exemplo?